# ReactJS force useState to set immediately appropriate value

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app with selecting logic but everything in this logic breaks because of "useState()". I know that "useState()" is asynchronous and value is not assigned immediately but to work my logic value is needed immediately when I click on the row. And the question is how to set value immediately in the "setEntry()" ?

This is my code:

```
const TableRow = (props) => {
const [entry, setEntry] = useState('');
const array = Object.entries(props);
const navigate = useNavigate();
let previousRow;

const deleteContact = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const id = e.target.getAttribute('id');

    await requester(urls.accountWithId + '/' + id, methods.delete);

    await requester(urls.contacts + '/' + id, methods.delete)
        .then(() => {
            navigate(urls.mainPage);
            notificationsReceiver('Contact is deleted successfully!');
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            alert(e.message);
        });
};

const checkIsSelected = (id) => {
    if (entry === id) {
        setEntry('');
        return;
    }

    setEntry(id);
};

const changeStyle = (e) => {
    const currentRowId = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('id');

    if (entry === '') {
        e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#E3E5E7';
        setEntry(currentRowId);
        previousRow = e.currentTarget;
    }
    else if (entry === currentRowId) {
        e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#F5F7FA';
        setEntry('');
    }
    else if (entry !== currentRowId) {
        setEntry(currentRowId);
        e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#E3E5E7';
        previousRow.style.display = '#F5F7FA';
        previousRow = e.currentTarget;
    }
};

const navigateToDetails = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const id = e.target.getAttribute('id');

    navigate(urls.details + '/:' + id);
};

const editContact = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const id = e.target.getAttribute('id');

    navigate(urls.editContact + '/:' + id);
}

return (
    <tr className={styles['contact-row']} id={array[1][1].id} onDoubleClick={navigateToDetails} key={array[1][1].id} onClick={(e) => { checkIsSelected(array[1][1].id); changeStyle(e); }}>
        <td id={array[1][1].id}>{array[1][1].name}</td>
        <td id={array[1][1].id}>{array[1][1].continentAndCountry}</td>
        <td id={array[1][1].id}>{array[1][1].email}</td>
        <td id={array[1][1].id}><a href={array[1][1].baseUrlForFreeGuyz + '/' + array[1][1].accountNameForFreeGuyz}>{array[1][1].accountNameForFreeGuyz}</a></td>
        <td id={array[1][1].id}><a href={array[1][1].baseUrlForInstagram + '/' + array[1][1].accountNameForInstagram}>{array[1][1].accountNameForInstagram}</a></td>
        <td id={array[1][1].id}><a href={array[1][1].baseUrlForTwitter + '/' + array[1][1].accountNameForTwitter}>{array[1][1].accountNameForTwitter}</a></td>
        <td id={array[1][1].id}>{array[1][1].accountType}</td>
        <td>
            {entry && <>
                <button className={`btn btn-warning ${styles['edit-button']}`} id={array[1][1].id} onClick={editContact}>Edit</button>
                <button className={`btn btn-danger ${styles['delete-button']}`} id={array[1][1].id} type="submit" onClick={deleteContact}>Delete</button></>}
        </td>
    </tr>
);
}

export default TableRow;
```

I'll be grateful if anyone can help me.

Comment: You are only setting state when you the `onClick` will be triggered, so I don't understand the question about setting the logic immediately. If you want to set default data, update the arguments of the `useState` hook.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of continuously calling `setSentry` for state updates, you can use a local variable to check value changes and after all, you can update `entry` at once.

```
const changeStyle = (e) => {
    //local variable to proceed the internal logic
    let updatedEntry = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('id')

    if (updatedEntry === currentRowId) {
        e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#F5F7FA';
        updatedEntry = ""
    } else {
        updatedEntry = currentRowId
        e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#E3E5E7';
        previousRow.style.display = '#F5F7FA';
        previousRow = e.currentTarget;
    }

    currentRowId = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('id');

    //only update `entry` state once after all
    setEntry(updatedEntry)
};
```